# How to get the center vertex position of all the faces of BoxGeometry in threejs?

Tags: three.js, geometry, center, vertex, face

I have a BoxGeometry here, which forms a cube,
what i want to acheive is to ***get the center vertex position of all the faces of the cube?***

```
const boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1.5,1.5,1.5,2,2,2);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color:0xffffff,
      wireframe:true,
});
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry,material);
```

[image: This is the cube i'm working on]

***Can anyone help me figure out this?***

Answer (score 4):

Each face is defined by a triplet of indices of vertices.

As an option to find centers:

```js
let centers = [];
let a = new THREE.Vector3(), b = new THREE.Vector3(), c = new THREE.Vector3();
let pos = boxGeometry.attributes.position;
let idx = boxGeometry.index;
let faces = idx.count / 3;
for(let i = 0; i < faces; i++){
  a.fromBufferAttribute(pos, idx.getX(i * 3 + 0));
  b.fromBufferAttribute(pos, idx.getX(i * 3 + 1));
  c.fromBufferAttribute(pos, idx.getX(i * 3 + 2));
  a.add(b).add(c).divideScalar(3); // center is the average of three vertices
  centers.push(a.clone());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply,
I used your code, but unfortunately it doesn't give the centre vertex of the faces, what it does is that it given me some vertices, and if i used those vertices in line geometry, i get some random lines over the cube i was working on.
This is the link of screenshot of the cube https://ibb.co/QfzHzKq
if you don't mind answering, can you atleast tell me a way to find atleast a center vertex position of just one face of the cube?

Comment: @mockingbird do we talk about faces (triangles) or about sides of a box? or something else?

Comment: @Marquizzo thanks for editing :) totally overlooked it.

Comment: sorry if i'm not clear enough before, we are talking about face of the box(cube).